# Protecting against Time-of-check to time-of-use?

Tags: c++, linux, file, unix, race-condition

I was reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use

They showed this code to be buggy and I totally understand why it's so:

```
if (access("file", W_OK) != 0) {
    exit(1);
}
// Attacker: symlink("/etc/passwd", "file");
fd = open("file", O_WRONLY);
// Actually writing over /etc/passwd
write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

But the real question is how to protect against this type of exploits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `O_NOFOLLOW` flag. It will cause the `open` to fail if `basename` of the path is a symbolic link. That would solve the described attack.

To cover links along the directory path, you can check whether `frealpath(fd, ...)` matches what you would expect.

Another way to prevent a process from overwriting `/etc/passwd` is to run it as non-root so that it won't have permission. Or, you can use chroot - or more generally, a container - to prevent the host system's `/etc/passwd` being visible to the process.

More generally though, filesystem TOCTOU is unsolvable at the moment on Linux. You would need transaction support either on filesystem or system call level - which are lacking.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure (and haven't tested it), but I think some of this might be mitigated by using the `O_PATH` `open` flag, possibly opening the file through `/proc/self/fd` after checking `fstat`. Or possibly using that with `name_to_handle_at` and `open_by_handle_at` (though that requires a specific capability to use).

Comment: "It will cause the open to fail if basename of the path is a symbolic link." a symbolic link file has destination in its contents so how this will work? any examples

Comment: @Dan If the file is a symbolic link, then open will simply fail. That's what O_NOFOLLOW does.

Comment: @eerorika but will that always work? what about hard links? maybe there is something I don't know of and can do something similar to symbol links...

Answer (score 1):

There is no failproof solution.

Be also aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). It might be relevant.

But you could adopt a system wide convention (and document it) that every program accessing a given file is using locking facilities like  [flock(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html).